# Solving a matrix pencil (quadratic eigenvalue) problem with Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, eigenvalues

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_pencil)

> The matrix pencil of degree $\ell$ is the matrix-valued function
> defined on the complex numbers $L(k) = \sum_{i=0}^{\ell} k^{i} A_{i}$.

Here $A_{\ell}$ are non-zero $n\times n$ complex matrices.

I am dealing with a situation where $n=4$, $\ell =2$, and the only relevant coefficient matrices

```
A0 = Y - X.Inverse[Y].X;
A1 = Inverse[Y].X - X.Inverse[Y];
A2 = Inverse[Y];
```

where

```
     X = {{-2 r t + x1, -p t, 1/2 (4 s t + x2), q t}, {-p t, x4, q t, x3/
    2}, {-2 s t - x2/2, -q t, -2 r t + x1, -p t}, {-q t, -(x3/
     2), -p t, x4}};
     Y = {{0, -p t, 0, -q t}, {-p t, 0, -q t, 0}, {0, -q t, 0, 
    p t}, {-q t, 0, p t, 0}};
```

The parameters $x1,x2,x3,x4$ are real and positive, and $p,q,r,s,t$ are real but not necessarily positive.

**Question:** I want to figure out for what *real* $k$ the determinant of the matrix pencil vanishes i.e. `Det[k^2 A2 + k A1 + A0] == 0`. I tried `Solve[Det[k^2 A2 + k A1 + A0] == 0, k]`, but the *Mathematica* keeps running with no output.

After digging further, I came to know about the *linear* method of solving such commonly known as the *quadratic eigenvalue problems* from [here](https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Ebai/Winter09/qep_slides.pdf), but could not understand how to implement it. Any help with my **Question** is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could try MatrixPencilSolve in the Wolfram Function Repository.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielLichtblau. Unfortunately, I do not find MatrixPencilSolve in ver 13.2

Comment: It’s in the Wolfram Function Repository.